# update span content with ajax

Tags: ajax

How could I make the votes update directly? Just like the votes on this site

I have this function:

```
function ratePost(id, rating) {
    $.post("ratepost.php", {postID: id, rating: rating}, function(data){alert(data+" return val"); });
}

<span class="karma"><?php echo $rating ?></span>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Don't you know how to set the text or do you want to run that function automatically or...?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do 2 things in order for it to work:

1. set a id to your display span and leave it empty (no need for the php echo), eg

`<span id = 'rating'...></span>`

1. in your ajax callback function, do something like

`function(data){document.getElementById("rating").innerHTML = data;}`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are with a javascript library like jQuery.

So you can target your span like that in your callback :

```
function(data){ $(".karma").html(data) }
```

Here it is what you want (I think :-)) :

```
function ratePost(id, rating) {
    $.post("ratepost.php", {postID: id, rating: rating}, function(data){
        var current = $(".karma").html();
        $(".karma").html( current + 1 );
    });
}

<span class="karma"><?php echo $rating ?></span>
```

Comment: It does just remove the number thats inside that span :/

Comment: Yes, it will replace all in your span.

But what is the content of your data callback ?

Comment: it does just ad the number 1 beside it :/ if the post has -16 rating and i upvote or downvote it just adds a 1 like -161

Comment: You need a parseInt : `$(".karma").html( parseInt(current) + 1 );`
And then you have to handle the +1 and -1.